# Does a user need to authorize everytime when he logs in to make an external callout which is configured in auth provider?

Tags: salesforce, integration, apex, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I've 2 salesforce org where one Org A need to fetch data from Org B so I configured named credentials and auth provider and authenticated as Org B which is working perfectly.

My doubt is what happens when the access token expires or what happens when the user logs out and logs in after n days does the user need to authenticate again by going through setup -> named credentials -> check (authenticate flow on save) to make an API request

Please clarify I'm new to Salesforce learning and correct me if I'm wrong.

I don't have tried any particular solution